# How to correctly use the add operation for an array list

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, double

I need to be able to add a double value to an array list with a method. This is the one I created:

```
        public void addPrice(double nPrice) {
    if (nPrice >= 0) {
        priceList.add(nPrice);
    }
    else {
        priceList.add(null);
    }
}
```

It is supposed to take the price that needs to be added as a parameter and not return anything. This price has to be at least 0. If the price is negative then nothing is done or added. I thought this would work but when I try the value 1.2 as my test dictates the value is not added to the least. Am I using the add operation wrong or is there something else I am missing?

Comment: How are you testing it? Some more context will help us answer.

Comment: show us how you are printing the array list, it would be better to copy paste the whole program

Comment: If you don't want anything to be added, then there should be no `else` block.

Comment: Can we see how the list is defined?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see all of your code so it's possible you're creating/accessing your ArrayList incorrectly.

```
ArrayList<Double> priceList = new ArrayList<>();
priceList.addPrice(1.2);

public void addPrice(double nPrice) {
    if (nPrice >= 0) {
        priceList.add(nPrice);
    }
//Don't do anything if the price is not valid.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Tester{
public static void main(String[] args){
    addPrice(1.2);
    System.out.println(priceList.get(0));//this prints 1.2
}
/**
 * Assuming you are using an arraylist like so.
 * Remember to use a list you must use the class not
 * just the primitive type.
 */
static ArrayList<Double> priceList = new ArrayList<>();

public static  void addPrice(double nPrice) {
if (nPrice >= 0) {
    priceList.add(nPrice);
}
else {
    priceList.add(null);
}
}
}
```

Comment: The 'else' really should be a 0 instead of a null value.